# can we do deep tie with a c++1y std::tie() -like function?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, tie

Is there a way to write a variant of `std::tie` in c++11/1y that ties deeply into a tuple. That is, one in which  `tie((x,y),z) = make_tuple(make_tuple(1,2),3)` binds `x, y, z` to `1, 2 and 3`, respectively as in the following example. It would be nice. Thanks.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int x, y ,z;
  auto t = make_tuple(1,2);
  std::tie(y,x)= t;
  //std::tie((x,y),z) = make_tuple(t,3); //not working
  cout << x << y << z << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can go:

```
std::forward_as_tuple(std::tie(x, y), z) = std::make_tuple(t, 3);
```

`std::forward_as_tuple` works very similarly to `std::tie`, except that unlike it it will not reject `std::tie(x, y)` as an argument.

Comment: Too bad they didn't think of a shorter name for it.  Works great, looks ugly.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you're looking for `std::tuple_cat`:

```
std::tie(x,y,z) = std::tuple_cat(t, make_tuple(3));
```

You can string together `tuples` as one long tuple, to avoid dealing with nested tuples. I think the solution to flattening nested tuples would be more complex.

---

Just to make a clarification on how `std::tie` works (I think). `std::tie` constructs a tuple of lvalue references from its arguments. When you use the assignment operator, [copy assignments are performed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff5f307def023e62). `std::tie((x,y),z)` doesn't do what you think. You're subjecting `(x,y)` to the comma operator, where x is discarded. There is no magic going on, where nesting is determined by parentheses. If one of the arguments to `std::tie` is a tuple, then the corresponding argument should be a tuple as well. i.e.: `std::tie(tuple, 3) = std::make_tuple(std::make_tuple(1, 2), 3)`. However this is not what you want, which is where my suggestion comes from, because it doesn't seem like your intention is to flatten a nested tuple.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But I wanted to have someway of deep tie-ing. I don't know if it is possible at all, but it will be really convenient.

Comment: @TingL I will look in the morning, unless someone comes along and has an answer. But I am not clear on what you mean by deep tie-ing.

Comment: @remabel,  I mean, whether we can make tie recursive, i.e. when tie-ing the first component on the RHS, check to see if that component is a tuple. If so, unpack the first component and tie its components to corresponding things on the LHS. Descend until there is no tuple type and return to the second component of the root tuple. I suspect it might be possible because the template programming part of C++ itself is Turing complete.