# Unpacking nested tuples in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, tie

`std::tie` provides a convenient way to unpack the contents of a tuple in C++ into separately defined variables, like the sample below illustrates

```
int a, b, c, d, e, f;

auto tup1 = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3);
std::tie(a, b, c) = tup1;
```

However, if we have a nested tuple like below

```
auto tup2 = std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3, std::make_tuple(4, 5, 6));
```

attempting to compile the code

```
std::tie(a, b, c, std::tie(d, e, f)) = tup2;
```

fails with an error

```
/tmp/tuple.cpp:10: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::tuple<int&, int&, int&>&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::tuple<int&, int&, int&>’
  std::tie(a, b, c, std::tie(d, e, f)) = tup2;
                            ^
```

Is there an idiomatic way to unpack a tuple of tuples in C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298732/can-we-do-deep-tie-with-a-c1y-stdtie-like-function

Comment: You can make a [temporary tuple for nesting](http://ideone.com/s3YLG9), though it's not as nice looking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you know that there is no risk, you can convert an rvalue reference to an lvalue one through the following helper function :

```
template <class T>
constexpr T &lvalue(T &&v) {
    return v;
}
```

You can then use it thusly :

```
std::tie(a, b, c, lvalue(std::tie(d, e, f))) = tup2;
```

In your case there is indeed no problem in doing that, since the inner tuple only has to be alive for the duration of the statement, and it is (exactly) the case.

Comment: Is it possible to define a composite function `ltie`, where calling `ltie(a, b, c)` is equivalent to calling `lvalue(std::tie(a, b, c))` in order to simplify the code to `ltie(a, b, c, ltie(d, e, f)) = tup2`;

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't. If you bury the temporary tuple into a function, it will then be local to that function, and won't live long enough. You could make it a macro instead.

Comment: Or just use `forward_as_tuple`.