# Recursive std::tie in C++

Tags: c++, std

I've been coding in C++ for a long time and recently come across tying for pairs. Please can someone explain why the following code doesn't work or suggest an equivalent replacement?

```
pair<int,pair<int,int>> x = {10,{3,5}};
int w, u, v;
tie(w,tie(u,v)) = x;
```

I can get around it with this:

```
w = x.ff;
tie(u,v) = x.ss;
```

It just doesn't feel as nice.
Many thanks

Comment: `tie(u,v)` returns a tuple by value, so the outer `tie` would have capture that **temporary** value by reference, that is forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

Because `std::tie` takes *lvalue* references, and since nested `std::tie` returns a *prvalue* of a tuple, you cannot bind an rvalue to an lvalue reference.

Try this

```
std::pair<int,std::pair<int,int>> x = {10,{3,5}};
int w, u, v;
auto t = std::tie(u,v);
std::tie(w, t) = x;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6bn9v3rd1)

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because we can **only write lvalue as an argument** inside the tie.
For more information you can check: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tie/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this post ([can we do deep tie with a c++1y std::tie() -like function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298732/can-we-do-deep-tie-with-a-c1y-stdtie-like-function))
I can do this:

```
forward_as_tuple(w,tie(u,v)) = x;
```